# Recursion in lambda expressions

Tags: vimscript, functions

Alright, so I have two recursion functions with the exact same purpose:

```
let Fac = { n -> n == 0 ? 1 : n * Fac(n - 1) }

function! Fact(n)
    return a:n == 0 ? 1 : a:n * Fact(a:n - 1)
endfunction
```

While `Fact` works fine, recursive use of `Fac` seems to confuse vim:

```
:echo Fac(10)
Error detected while processing function <lambda>20:                                                                                  
line    1:
E117: Unknown function: Fac
-1
```

Does lambda expression not support recursion, or did I call `Fac` in an incorrect way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible, but you must refer to Fac as a "global" with `g:` to allow the lambda to refer to "itself," even if it is not actually defined already.

```
let Fac = { n -> n == 0 ? 1 : n * g:Fac(n - 1) }
echo Fac(6)
```

If we want to avoid global variables there are two issues:

1. Fac needs to be "dummy defined" for any closure to take effect.
2. At script level, the function is called s:Fac.  Although it will work inside a function, with local variables.

It is possible to do this at script scope using `s:` as follows:

```
let s:Fac = { n -> 1 }
let s:Fac = { n -> n == 0  ? 1 : n * s:Fac(n - 1) }
echo s:Fac(6)
```

Or at local function scope:

```
function DoSomething()
    let Fac = { n -> 1 }
    let Fac = { n -> n == 0 ? 1 : n * Fac(n - 1) }
    echo Fac(6)                                                                
endfunction
call DoSomething()
```

vim9script improves this situation somewhat, since it allows "declaring" variables by type annotation.  It also works at script scope.

```
vim9script                                                                       
                                                                               
var Fac: func(number): number                                                    
Fac = (n: number): number => {                                                   
    return n == 0 ? 1 : n * Fac(n - 1)                                         
}
```

Comment: What a bizarre behaviour... is it still possible to define `Fac` at the script level, or must I be declaring with `function` keyword?

Comment: Yes, but for syntax reasons you must use `g:`  or `s:` as follows:


`let Fac = { n -> 1 } |
let Fac = { n -> n == 0 ? 1 : n * g:Fac(n - 1) } |
echo Fac(6)
`
~OR~


`let s:Fac = { n -> 1 } |
let s:Fac = { n -> n == 0  ? 1 : n * s:Fac(n - 1) } |
echo s:Fac(6)
`

Comment: Tested in ex mode, it looks like vim is comfortable even without the dummy in this way: ```:echo Fac;
E121: Undefined variable: Fac;
:let Fac = { n -> n == 0 ? 1 : n * g:Fac(n - 1) };

:echo Fac(8);
40320```

Comment: @Futarimiti, you're right this works because the function is global and has late binding.  I have updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it's worth to do but, at least, it's worth to mention that we can also parse the call stack to get lambda's name. And so we have

```
" Calling the caller
function! Self(...) abort
    return expand('<stack>')->split('[\d\+\]\.\.\|\s')[-2]->call(a:000)
endfunction

" will print 720
:echo call({ n -> n <= 1 ? 1 : n * Self(n - 1) }, [6])
```

Comment: Not exactly what I'm looking for but really innovative idea :) +1